# Atualizar tabela sem atualizar página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa noite.
Tenho a seguinte tabela no meu painel de PEDIDOS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando colocar uma função para atualizar apenas o Status a cada 5 segundos.

Já vi vários exemplos na internet e consegui fazer funcionar apenas dois.
Um deles é esse que eu estou usando:

```html
javascript

<script>
var tempo = window.setInterval(carrega, 5000);
function carrega()
{
$('#tabela-atualizar').load("pedidos/listar.php");
}

</script>


php

<td id="tabela-atualizar"><label class="'.$statuscolor.'">'.$status.'</label></td>
```

O código funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que quando atualizo a página manualmente, passa-se os 5 segundo setados, o status é alterado mas a tabela se desconfigura totalmente como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para tentar resolver esse problema. Desde já, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

## "Resolução"

*Você está tentando carregar toda a página no #tabela-atualizar*

A url **pedidos/listar.php** é a página atual que você está acessando, então dar load nela apenas irá imprimir ela novamente.

Você está técnicamente fazendo isso:

```
<script>
var tempo = window.setInterval(carrega, 5000);

function carrega() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

O *"Correto"* seria você criar uma página chamada ***pedidos/listarContent.php***

E nela você coloca quase o mesmo conteúdo da ***pedidos/listar.php***, mas nela você irá remover as tags html, head, body, deixando apenas o conteúdo da listagem

Exemplo Antes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Página de Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="recebeConteudo">
O conteúdo da Listar vem aqui
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo Como deve ficar, sem as tags de uma página html.:

```
<div class="recebeConteudo">
O conteúdo da Listar vem aqui
</div>
```

E, para finalizar você faria a seguinte modificação no seu script:

```
<script>
var tempo = window.setInterval(carrega, 5000);

function carrega() {
    $('.recebeConteudo').remove();
    $('body').load("pedidos/listarContent.php");

}
</script>
```

***$('.recebeConteudo').remove()*** fará com que o a lista de pedidos seja deletada da página

E ***$('body').load("pedidos/listarContent.php");*** irá recriar a .recebeConteudo na página com o status e as demais informações atualizadas

**ESSA DEFINITIVAMENTE NÃO É A MANEIRA CORRETA DE FAZER ISSO!**

Seria melhor *(pra essa solução)* você alimentar o status com um Ajax sendo feito pra uma página com  a id do pedido e retornando o status nessa requisição ajax e alimentando o status de cada pedido.

---

### Isso vai te dar trabalho...

Pelo que percebi, aparentemente você está tentando implementar um sistema de delivery ou algo do gênero.

Usar o setInterval vai fazer a página ser carregada a cada 5 segundos, independente se o status do pedido mudou ou não, e isso pode te gerar grandes problemas se essa página estiver sendo visualizada por muita gente ou se no futuro você for implementar o mesmo painel pra mais pessoas, ou até mesmo consumir uma api que exiba o status do pedido pro cliente.

Isso porque cada requisição vai ter um custo de consumo de máquina, fará um SELECT no banco de dados, e, bem, isso vai ser um problema se replicado em larga escala.

**Recomendo** que estude o que é WebSocket, existe até uma biblioteca bem completinha da implementação de servidores WebSockets em PHP chamada "Ratchet" recomendo que dê uma olhada nela ;)

[Link do Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)